# How to upload a file (csv or text) and read contents in Zope framework

Tags: mysql, csv, text, upload, zope

I have a web page that users are supposed to use to upload CSV contents to a MySQL database, how do I get the contents using an external method and insert them to the database?

First I have a form which users are using to upload the files:

```html
<form role="form" action="scripts/processUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file_name" id="file_name" accept=".csv,.txt">
        <input type="hidden" name="type_of_upload" value="cell_line">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="align-content:center" id="i_submit">Upload</button>
    <script>
        $('#i_submit').click(function () {
            //check whether browser fully supports all File API
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                //get the file size and file type from file input field
                var fsize = $('#file_name')[0].files[0].size;
                var ftype = $('#file_name')[0].files[0].type;
                var fname = $('#file_name')[0].files[0].name;

                if (fsize > 5242880) //do something if file size more than 5 mb (1048576)
                {
                    alert("Type :" + ftype + " | " + fsize + " bites\n(File: " + fname + ") Too big!");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
            }
        });

        $('#i_submit').click(function () {
            //check whether browser fully supports all File API
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                //get the file size and file type from file input field
                var fsize = $('#file_name')[0].files[0].size;
                var ftype = $('#file_name')[0].files[0].type;
                var fname = $('#file_name')[0].files[0].name;
                //alert(ftype)
                switch (ftype) {
                    case 'application/vnd.ms-excel':
                    case 'text/plain':
                        //alert("Acceptable image file!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert('Unsupported File format!');
                }

            } else {
                alert("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
            }
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

Part of the procesUpload script is shown below, I am using request to get the file:

```
data=context.fileReader(data_file=context.REQUEST.file_name.name)
print data
return printed
```

The fileReader is an external method that takes in the data file and is supposed to read the contents:

```
def readFiles(data_file):
    with open(data_file,'r') as f:
        data=f.readlines()
        for line in data:
            words = line.split(",")
            data_read.append(words)
    return data_read
```

But after doing all this, I am getting:

```
Error Type: IOError
Error Value: (13, 'Permission denied'),
```

Can someone with experience on how to upload and read the contents of an uploaded file in Zope help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution didn't actually need an external method, I did it with one line in a script to read the contents of the uploaded file as follows;

```
uploaded_data=context.REQUEST.get('uploaded_file').readlines()
```